# JHipster Angular unit test cannot find module 'ngx-easy-table' from component file

Tags: jestjs, jhipster, ngx-easy-table

###### **Motivation for or Use Case**

I want to use the third-party library [ngx-easy-table](https://ngx-easy-table.eu/#/) in my components of a bare bone JHipster project.

###### **Overview of the issue**

Unit test fails when importing an external module (`ngx-easy-table`) from component file. However, running the application works fine.

`./mvnw` works fine (and actually works in the browser too ;)

`./npmw test` fails:

```
# ./npmw test -- home.component                                                                                     ✘ 1
Using node installed locally v16.14.0
Using npm installed locally 8.6.0

> jhipster-ngx-easy-table@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT pretest
> npm run lint


> jhipster-ngx-easy-table@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT lint
> eslint . --ext .js,.ts


/Users/TestUser/jhipster-ngx-easy-table/src/test/javascript/cypress/support/commands.ts
   81:53  warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  120:34  warning  Unexpected any. Specify a different type  @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any

✖ 2 problems (0 errors, 2 warnings)


> jhipster-ngx-easy-table@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT test
> ng test --coverage --log-heap-usage -w=2 "home.component"

 FAIL  src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.spec.ts
  ● Test suite failed to run

    Cannot find module 'ngx-easy-table' from 'src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.ts'

    Require stack:
      src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.ts
      src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.spec.ts

       6 | import { AccountService } from 'app/core/auth/account.service';
       7 | import { Account } from 'app/core/auth/account.model';
    >  8 | import { Columns, Config, DefaultConfig } from 'ngx-easy-table';
         | ^
       9 |
      10 | @Component({
      11 |   selector: 'jhi-home',

      at Resolver.resolveModule (node_modules/jest-resolve/build/resolver.js:324:11)
      at Object.<anonymous> (src/main/webapp/app/home/home.component.ts:8:1)

----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File      | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files |       0 |        0 |       0 |       0 |
----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 failed, 1 total
Tests:       0 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        1.273 s
Ran all test suites matching /home.component/i.
```

###### **Reproduce the error**

I followed the [installation guide](https://ngx-easy-table.eu/#/installation) from `ngx-easy-table` and did the following steps:

`jhipster generate` with default values

`npm install @angular/cdk@13.3.1 --save`
`npm install ngx-easy-table --save`

added module to `shared-libs.module.ts`:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { NgbModule } from '@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap';
import { InfiniteScrollModule } from 'ngx-infinite-scroll';
import { FontAwesomeModule } from '@fortawesome/angular-fontawesome';
import { TranslateModule } from '@ngx-translate/core';
import { TableModule } from 'ngx-easy-table';

@NgModule({
  exports: [FormsModule, CommonModule, NgbModule, InfiniteScrollModule, FontAwesomeModule, ReactiveFormsModule, TranslateModule, TableModule],
})
export class SharedLibsModule {}
```

added to the end of `home.component.html`:

```
...
<ngx-table [configuration]="configuration"
           [data]="data"
           [columns]="columns">
</ngx-table>
```

changed `home.component.ts`:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { takeUntil } from 'rxjs/operators';

import { AccountService } from 'app/core/auth/account.service';
import { Account } from 'app/core/auth/account.model';
import { Columns, Config, DefaultConfig } from 'ngx-easy-table';

@Component({
  selector: 'jhi-home',
  templateUrl: './home.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./home.component.scss'],
})
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
  public configuration: Config;
  public columns: Columns[];

  public data = [
    {
      phone: '+1 (934) 551-2224',
      age: 20,
      address: { street: 'North street', number: 12 },
      company: 'ZILLANET',
      name: 'Valentine Webb',
      isActive: false,
    },
    {
      phone: '+1 (948) 460-3627',
      age: 31,
      address: { street: 'South street', number: 12 },
      company: 'KNOWLYSIS',
      name: 'Heidi Duncan',
      isActive: true,
    },
  ];

  account: Account | null = null;

  private readonly destroy$ = new Subject<void>();

  constructor(private accountService: AccountService, private router: Router) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.accountService
      .getAuthenticationState()
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
      .subscribe(account => (this.account = account));

      this.configuration = { ...DefaultConfig };
      this.configuration.searchEnabled = true;
      // ... etc.
      this.columns = [
        { key: 'phone', title: 'Phone' },
        { key: 'age', title: 'Age' },
        { key: 'company', title: 'Company' },
        { key: 'name', title: 'Name' },
        { key: 'isActive', title: 'STATUS' },
      ];
  }

  login(): void {
    this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  }

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }
}
```

changed `angular.json`:

```
...
"styles": ["src/main/webapp/content/scss/vendor.scss", "src/main/webapp/content/scss/global.scss", "node_modules/ngx-easy-table/style.css"],
...
```

changed `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "strictPropertyInitialization": false
...
```

###### **JHipster Version(s)**

```
# jhipster --version
INFO! Switching to JHipster installed locally in current project's node repository (node_modules)
7.8.1
```

###### **JHipster configuration**

````
❯ jhipster info
INFO! Switching to JHipster installed locally in current project's node repository (node_modules)

        ██╗ ██╗   ██╗ ████████╗ ███████╗   ██████╗ ████████╗ ████████╗ ███████╗
        ██║ ██║   ██║ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═══██╗ ██╔════╝ ╚══██╔══╝ ██╔═════╝ ██╔═══██╗
        ██║ ████████║    ██║    ███████╔╝ ╚█████╗     ██║    ██████╗   ███████╔╝
  ██╗   ██║ ██╔═══██║    ██║    ██╔════╝   ╚═══██╗    ██║    ██╔═══╝   ██╔══██║
  ╚██████╔╝ ██║   ██║ ████████╗ ██║       ██████╔╝    ██║    ████████╗ ██║  ╚██╗
   ╚═════╝  ╚═╝   ╚═╝ ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝       ╚═════╝     ╚═╝    ╚═══════╝ ╚═╝   ╚═╝
                            https://www.jhipster.tech
Welcome to JHipster v7.8.1

Welcome to the JHipster Information Sub-Generator

##### **JHipster Version(s)**

\```
jhipster-ngx-easy-table@0.0.1-SNAPSHOT /Users/TestUser/jhipster-ngx-easy-table
└── generator-jhipster@7.8.1

\```


##### **JHipster configuration, a `.yo-rc.json` file generated in the root folder**


<details>
<summary>.yo-rc.json file</summary>
<pre>
{
  "generator-jhipster": {
    "applicationType": "monolith",
    "authenticationType": "jwt",
    "baseName": "jhipsterNgxEasyTable",
    "blueprints": [],
    "buildTool": "maven",
    "cacheProvider": "ehcache",
    "clientFramework": "angularX",
    "clientPackageManager": "npm",
    "clientTheme": "none",
    "clientThemeVariant": "",
    "creationTimestamp": 1655819689067,
    "cypressCoverage": false,
    "databaseType": "sql",
    "devDatabaseType": "h2Disk",
    "devServerPort": 4200,
    "dtoSuffix": "DTO",
    "enableGradleEnterprise": false,
    "enableHibernateCache": true,
    "enableSwaggerCodegen": false,
    "enableTranslation": true,
    "entitySuffix": "",
    "jhiPrefix": "jhi",
    "jhipsterVersion": "7.8.1",
    "jwtSecretKey": "YourJWTSecretKeyWasReplacedByThisMeaninglessTextByTheJHipsterInfoCommandForObviousSecurityReasons",
    "languages": ["en"],
    "messageBroker": false,
    "nativeLanguage": "en",
    "otherModules": [],
    "packageName": "org.example.jhipster.ngxeasytable",
    "pages": [],
    "prodDatabaseType": "postgresql",
    "reactive": false,
    "searchEngine": false,
    "serverPort": "8080",
    "serverSideOptions": [],
    "serviceDiscoveryType": "no",
    "skipCheckLengthOfIdentifier": false,
    "skipFakeData": false,
    "skipUserManagement": false,
    "testFrameworks": ["cypress"],
    "websocket": false,
    "withAdminUi": true
  }
}

</pre>
</details>


##### **JDL for the Entity configuration(s) `entityName.json` files generated in the `.jhipster` directory**

<details>
<summary>JDL entity definitions</summary>

<pre>

</pre>
</details>


##### **Environment and Tools**

openjdk version "11.0.15" 2022-04-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Homebrew (build 11.0.15+0)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Homebrew (build 11.0.15+0, mixed mode)

git version 2.36.1

node: v16.15.1

npm: 8.11.0

Docker version 20.10.16, build aa7e414

Docker Compose version v2.6.0


No change to package.json was detected. No package manager install will be executed.
Congratulations, JHipster execution is complete!
Sponsored with ❤️  by @oktadev.
````